# How to integrate PurgeCSS with Angular CLI project

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, css-purge

I have an Angular project created with Angular CLI, so I have angular.json file for configuring the build.

I wanted to integrate PurgeCSS as it seems to be a great tool to reduce the size of our CSS bundle.

On [PurgeCSS website](https://www.purgecss.com/#webpack), they explain how to integrate with Webpack. I found a tutorial that explains how to add [custom webpack integration with Angular CLI](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-webpack-config/).

**Did anyone have a successful example of PurgeCSS integrated with Angular CLI project ?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I created this bash script to use PurgeCSS with my Angular app. It reduced my 'styles.css' file size from 63kb to only 3kb! Hope it works for you too.

**Steps:**

1. create a new file named `purgecss.sh` inside your project folder
2. insert the code below into `purgecss.sh` file
3. run `./purgecss.sh` from CLI

```
#!/bin/bash

# run production build
ng build --prod --output-hashing none

# go to the dist/yourProjectName folder
cd ./dist/yourProjectName

# make a new directory named 'css' (you can name it anything)
mkdir css

# run PurgeCSS & make a new '.css' file inside the 'css' directory
purgecss --css ./styles.css --content ./index.html ./*.js --out ./css

# replace the 'dist/yourProjectName/styles.css' file with the 'dist/yourProjectName/css/styles.css' file
mv ./css/styles.css ./styles.css

# delete the previously created 'css' directory
rm -r css
```

Comment: I haven't checked that yet @AlexanderGharibashvili

Comment: I had to change --out to --output, but other than that it works like an absolute charm. Reduced my styles size from 112 kB to 5.4 kB. Love it!

Answer (score 32):

There is another way which is more in line with Angular CLI and Webpack config:

You need to install

```
npm install -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack postcss-scss @fullhuman/postcss-purgecss
```

Then create a `webpack.config.js` config file:

```
const purgecss = require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss')

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          ident: 'postcss',
          syntax: 'postcss-scss',
          plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-import'),
            require('autoprefixer'),
            purgecss({
              content: ['./**/*.html'],
              // Example to let PurgeCss know how to exclude cdk and mat prefixes if your using Angular CDK and Angular Material
              whitelistPatterns: [/^cdk-|mat-/]
            })
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Then change your `angular.json` file to use this new configurations:

```
...
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
  "options": {
    "customWebpackConfig": {
      "path": "webpack.config.js"
    },
    ...
  }
},
...
```

Make sure you run this configuration only in production mode, when you bundle the final application.

Hope this helps.

I created a post to explain how in detail - https://medium.com/@joao.a.edmundo/angular-cli-tailwindcss-purgecss-2853ef422c02

Comment: How do I do this if I already have a `"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",`?  This is used for the `ng build --prod` command. Can I use multiple builders somehow?

Comment: For me it seems to not work when I have some import inside my style.scss. E.g. @import 'custom-variables';

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60210139/post-css-not-finding-paths-from-node-modules

Comment: @user2619824 "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser" is a replacement for the default builder.

Answer (score 19):

This configuration works for me and giving me results from `126kb` to `34kb` on my `styles.[hash].css` output for production build.

First, install this:

`npm install -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack purgecss-webpack-plugin`

Then, create `webpack.config.js` in the root of the project:

```
const glob = require('glob');
const PurgeCSSPlugin = require('purgecss-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new PurgeCSSPlugin({ paths: glob.sync('./src/**/*.html', { nodir: true }) })
  ]
};
```

and edit your `angular.json` configuration as follows:

```
"architect": {
   "build": {
     "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
     "options": {
       "customWebpackConfig": {
         "path": "webpack.config.js"
       },
       ...
```

My result without this plugin:

```
styles.ca3c7399cc89e60cfa2d.css   | styles        | 128.99 kB
```

And now with the `purgecss-webpack-plugin`:

```
styles.ca3c7399cc89e60cfa2d.css   | styles        |  34.46 kB
```

Which is amazing, first when I saw this output I went checked my app in the browser and all styles have been included properly :-).

Only downside may be that this doesn't work on inlined html if any in angular components, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the great solution. I want to add an addition:
glob.sync('./src/**/*.html' selecting HTML files might be caused bugs. Because you can set a class name in TS files. Selecting all files ('./src/**/*') is a good choice.

Comment: Note: since Webpackage 5: `const { PurgeCSSPlugin } = require('purgecss-webpack-plugin');
`

Comment: Also with the modification of @MehmetErim, it still removes to much (for simple projects this might work, for advanced one you probably will encounter some strange styling problems)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply run the following commands in your project root directory

```
npm i -D postcss-import postcss-loader postcss-scss
ng add ngx-build-plus
```

In angular.json, make the following replacements in `"architect"` section:

`"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser"` with `"builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser"` under `"build"`,

`"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server"` with `"builder": "ngx-build-plus:dev-server"` under `"serve"`,

`"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma"` with `"builder": "ngx-build-plus:karma"` under `"test"`,

You should also add `"extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js"` under options in the respected sections.

Comment: you have told to add webpack.config.js in last line, but what should be the content of it ?